# How to fetch firestore data via reference value in a key

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, angular7

[image]

here is the multiple document for offer and each offer cantains bidderId that is referenced to users collection and user id.

I want to fetch offer list contains user collection.

I am using angularfire and here is my code.

```
this.liveOffers=this.db.collection("offers",ref => ref.where('offerExpired', '==', 0).where('isStart', '==', 1)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
map(actions => actions.map(a => {
  const data={} = a.payload.doc.data() as offer;
  const id = a.payload.doc.id;
  var bidder=this.db.doc(data.bidderId).snapshotChanges().subscribe(key=>{
    console.log(key.payload.data());
  });
  return { id, ...data,bidder };
}))   );
```

Here console.log(key.payload.data()); is logging the data for user but it can not bind with bidder variable and i can not use the user object in front end.

Please let me know how can I fetch the offer record with user details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `switchMap` and `combineLatest` to get it done.

This is a pseudo-code approach

```
const temp = []
this.offers$ = this.db.collection().snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(auctions=>{
    //we save all auctions in temp and return just the bidderId 

    return auctions.map(auction=>{
      const data={} = a.payload.doc.data() as offer;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      temp.push({id, ...data})
      return data.bidderId
    })


  }),
  switchMap(bidderIds=>{
    // here you'll have all bidderIds and you need to return the array to query 
    // them to firebase
    return combineLatest(bidderIds.map(bidderId=> return this.db.doc(bidderId)))
  }),
  map(bidders=>{
    // here you'll get all bisders you'll have to set the bidder on each temp obj 
    // you saved previously
  })
)
```

Make sure you `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators'` not `'rxjs'`

Comment: Will you please elaborate this. I am using your code but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. It is working. But I think it is bit big and there might be way to optimize it. Also it is node-js server API and not for the web (JS). Again there might be similar solution for the web (JS)

Once you get data from snapshot object there is `_path` key in the object returned by data which again have `segments` which is array and contain collection and ID

```js
const gg = await firestore.collection('scrape').doc('x6F4nctCD').get();

console.log(JSON.stringify(gg.data(), null, 4));
console.log(gg.data().r._path.segments[0]);
console.log(gg.data().r._path.segments[1]);

const gg2 = await firestore
.collection(gg.data().r._path.segments[0])
.doc(gg.data().r._path.segments[1])
.get();

console.log(gg2.data());
```

```
{
    "fv": {
        "_seconds": 1578489994,
        "_nanoseconds": 497000000
    },
    "tsnowpo": 1578489992,
    "createdAt": {
        "_seconds": 1578489992,
        "_nanoseconds": 328000000
    },
    "r": {
        "_firestore": {
            "_settings": {
                "libName": "gccl",
                "libVersion": "3.1.0",
                "servicePath": "firestore.googleapis.com",
                "port": 443,
                "clientConfig": {},
                "scopes": [
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"
                ]
            },
            "_settingsFrozen": true,
            "_serializer": {},
            "_projectId": "sss",
            "_lastSuccessfulRequest": 1578511337407,
            "_preferTransactions": false,
            "_clientPool": {
                "concurrentOperationLimit": 100,
                "activeClients": {},
                "terminated": false
            }
        },
        "_path": {
            "segments": [
                "egpo",
                "TJTHMkxOx1C"
            ]
        }
    }
}
egpo
TJTHMkxOx1C
{ name: 'Homeware' }
```